# Is it possible to map foreign keys with hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, annotations, foreign-keys

I have a class called `BusinessUser` which has a business id, and has an object called `BusinessData`. In the `BusinessData` class, there's an `ArrayList` of `Campaign` objects as shown below:

```
@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class BusinessData {
    @Transient
    private ArrayList<Campaign> campaigns;
    /...
}
```

In the `Campaign` class, there's a business id which is supposed to be a foreign key that references the business id column in the business user table.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Campaign {

    @ManyToOne
    private long businessId;
    /...
}
```

Is there a way I can map the value `businessId` to the `businessId` in the `BusinessUser` class WITHOUT having to have `Campaign` hold a `BusinessUser` object? Or should I simply add a `BusinessUser` object and map the foreign key that way?

Also, I don't know if I'm wrong about this. If I have to hold a `BusinessUser` object, it'll contain a `BusinessData` object, which will contain an `ArrayList` of `Campaign` objects, which will contain another `BusinessUser` and so on and so forth... Or am I wrong in thinking that it's a never ending cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are *wrong* and *right* in thinking that it is a never ending cycle,

this is wrong because `BusinessData` (although containing a `ArrayList<Campaign>`) get's it's data from the database.

This means it could contain a `BusinessUser` who does not have `BusinessData`. so the looping stops here.

But you are right if the `ArrayList<Campaign>` in `BusinessData` contains a `BusinessUser` who does have `BusinessData`.

That said, the loop is the same in the DataBase.

You could in theory write a SQL that goes like this:

```
SELECT BU.businessId
FROM BusinessUser BU
INNER JOIN BusinessData BD ON BU.businessId = BD.businessId
INNER JOIN campaigns C ON BD.campaignsId = C.Id
    AND C.businessId = BU.businessId
```

This will give you a result of all `BusinessUser` which are contained inside the `ArrayList<Campaing>` which are equal to the selected `BusinessUser`.

Tho not wrong, it might be something to consider.

That said, again, you should map your `Campaign` like so:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Campaign {

    @ManyToOne
    private BusinessUser businessUser;
    /...
}
```

Note to the `private BusinessUser businessUser;` !

Comment: I found this approach as well but heard it's bad design. would `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="business_id", table="business_users")`. If that doesn't work, then I'll definitely go with your solution. Thank you so much for your thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

@Join column(name="reference_column_name") annotation can be used above that property or field of class that is being referenced from some other entity.

Comment: But if I used that just above `private long businessId` how would it know to reference the table BusinessUsers as opposed to the Campaign table delegated in that class? I would have to add an object `BusinessUser` right? So there's no way around that?